# Cannot boot Ubuntu 19.10 after changing user password

Tags: boot, usb-drive, 19.10

I cannot boot Ubuntu 19.10 on my hp laptop suddenly. When I try to, it freezes on the booting screen. I do not know if this is related, I changed the user password before it won't boot anymore. Is there a solution to this? By the way I boot the OS via a USB hardrive.

Edit:

It actually used to boot and it worked smoothly until I cannot boot it anymore.I had upgraded it from 18.04 a few weeks ago.

Edit2:
I am using hp 240 G4.
I cannot reset as I have stored a lot of work in it.
When I booted it in recovery mode the last output is 'Stopped read required files in advance.'And it won't advance further.
how can I solve this?

Edit3:
The hard drive I am using to boot is */dev/sdb2*.Should I run *fsck /dev/sdb2 -v* in root shell in recovery mode?

Edit4:
I cannot enter my root password in the root shell prompt.it says password incorrect.How can I change my root password?

Edit5:
When I boot it it recovery mode,it stops at 'Stopped Read required files in advance'.Is there a solution to this?

Edit6:
Now I am using dell latitude E6430.I have booted another ubuntu live pendrive.Is there any commands that will help?
Also,is changing the user password related to the error?

Comment: I am sorry,but how do you access those options?I have searched these in the BIOs setup using f10.Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: How to set the BIOS/firmware to disable Quick Boot, disable Secure Boot, and use ACPI, are explained in your user manual, which also explains how to change the BIOS password. If you don't have it, flip your laptop over, and find the serial number sticker. On that sticker, there's also a model number. Click [edit] and add your model number to the original question. Please do not use any other number from anyplace else; only the model number on the serial number sticker will help find the correct manual.. Please don't put that into a Comment; please use [edit] instead.

Comment: I bought this laptop a few years ago,so I lost the user manual.Can I get it online?

Comment: You sure could... if you provide the model number from the serial number sticker. There are _many_ different 240 G4 models listed at HP support: https://www8.hp.com/us/en/search/search-results.html?ajaxpage=1#/page=1&/qt=240%20G4 - so please find the serial number sticker. On that sticker, there's also a model number. Click edit and add your model number to the original question, as was asked before. Please do not use any other number from anyplace else; only the model number on the serial number sticker will help find the correct manual..

Comment: @K7AAY How is the User Manual going to help in this situation?

Comment: How to set the BIOS/firmware to disable Quick Boot, disable Secure Boot, and use ACPI, are explained in the user manual

Comment: @K7AAY Thank you anyway for the user manual suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

**You probably have multiple problems.**

- what is on /dev/sda? I notice that you're booting to sdb
- the root password is not the same as your user password, unless you set it that way previously
- you may have a problem with `readahead`... left over from 18.04

**But first, let's check your file system...**

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier

  - `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb2`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Turns out that this is in a WSL environment, and I don't know anything about WSL. OP to start a new question.

Comment: You mean I should install another ubuntu on another pen drive /CD?And then should I enter into terminal and type these commands?By the way on sda5 there is windows 10.Thank you for your time.

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani no, you don't need to build another Ubuntu Live DVD/USB if you already have one. Just do the fsck in my answer, and let me know how it goes... if you can boot again, etc.

Comment: I cannot boot it.Is there an another way?

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani cannot boot what? The HDD or the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB? Did you do the fsck?

Comment: The ubuntu ard drive is not booting and in recovery mode,it stops at _Read required files in advance_.By the way I had changed my user password the day when it was last working.

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani before I give you commands that may help, I need to know if you've done the fsck. Also, in Recovery Mode, can you get to the root prompt? If it asks for a password, try the root password, or no password, or your username's password. Report back.

Comment: I cannot do the fsck as I can't get past the boot screen.Also when I enter Recovery mode, in root shell,it doesn't accept any password:root,user or nothing.I suspect it doesn't accept the root password because the g and h keys are not working properly and the root password has a h in it.

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani the `fsck` is done when booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. No password required. Later, for the root password, try the four combinations with/without the letters g and h... and then I'll give you further commands.

Comment: I have tried the fsck,still no luck.Also,in the root shell,when I tried different password combinations,I get the following output:

Comment: `sulogin:crypt failed:invalid arguement                                                     login incorrect`

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani Is your disk or /home folder encrypted? If so, have you been asked a password to unlock it? Are you confusing an encryption password with a root/user login password? You tried the fsck whilst booted to the Live flash key?

Comment: I don't understand.Can you please explain?

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani I have limited experience with encryption, although I have some opinion about where it is or is not appropriate to use it. My understanding is that you have to unlock an encrypted disk/folder to be able to access the contents, and your prior comment indicated "sulogin:crypt failed" which I take as an encryption error... I could be wrong. Do you remember selecting encryption when you installed Ubuntu?

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani If we could fsck your Ubuntu, or get to a root prompt, I might be able to help further...

Comment: Actually I installed the ubuntu terminal(Windows subsystem for linux) in Windows 10.Can it help?

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani I'm not familiar with WSL. Sorry.

Comment: So there is nothing I can do?Can I even use a command line in the ubuntu terminal on windows 10?Can I even recover my files?Anyway I am really grateful for all your help

Comment: Can I recover my files?

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani I really don't know, as I don't know anything about WSL. Maybe start a new question titled "Ubuntu file recovery in a broken WSL environment", with a link back to this question, and see if somebody knows. Hope so.

Comment: Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: I can get into a command-line in the menu where the OS you need to boot is selected i.e.the first menu after booting up the PC,with options like Ubuntu,Memory test,Advanced Boot Options for Ubuntu,Windows Recovery Environment etc.I can access the command-line by pressing 'c'.Although,the command-line is in grub...

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani If you choose "Ubuntu" or "Advanced Boot Options" does it take you to another selection that offers "Recovery Mode"?

Comment: By the way,I actually meant the GRUB Menu.Anyway,In Advanced Boot Options I do see Recovery Mode.

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani  In Recovery Mode, or in the `Terminal` that you installed before, can you get to the "#" prompt?

Comment: What is that and how do I access it?

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani Again, I don't know the WSL environment, so I really can't help you. Sorry.

Comment: It's okay.I actually meant how to access the '#' prompt.Can it help?

Comment: Recovery Mode, Root Access. If you can get to the # prompt, we might be able to do something.

Comment: OK,I got it.I'll try to get to the prompt somehow.Anyway,Can I use the command-line accessed by 'c' in the GRUB Menu?

Comment: @DevaSalilSonyRani No, the c in GRUB menu won't help.

Comment: OK,thank you again for trying to help me.Let me see if I can get into the root prompt.