# Error-Stopped Read required files in advance

Tags: boot, 19.10

I had posted a question regarding ubuntu 19.10 not booting before.When I boot it in recovery mode,I found the problem.After starting gnome display manager,it stops at *Stopped Read required files in advance*.It does not advance further.I had waited for a long time but no luck.Is there any way to solve this without re-installing?I had saved a lot of work so I can't reset it.

Edit: 
I cannot enter the root shell prompt in recovery mode as It keeps asking the root password and is not accepting any.How can I solve this too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot boot ubuntu 19.10 on laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202684/cannot-boot-ubuntu-19-10-on-laptop)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. VTC.